# Error: Query execution failed for dataset. Is my query correct for my dataset SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2014

I'm trying to use SET,IF,ALTER TABLE. When i run the report it gives me a error 'Query execution failed for dataset'.

This is the query for the dataset:

```
declare @DOB date
declare @NO VARCHAR (30)
declare @ID VARCHAR(30)
set @DOB = @DOB
set @NO = @NO
set @ID =@ID
IF @DOB is null
begin
SELECT DISTINCT [Name]
into tempName
FROM  [Patient]
where [No_]= @NO
or[Id No_] = @ID 
END
else 
IF @DH is null
begin 
SELECT DISTINCT [Name]
into tempName
FROM  [Patient]
where DATEOFBIRTH = @DOB
or [Id No_] = @ID
END
else 
IF @ID is null
begin
SELECT DISTINCT [Name]
into tempName
FROM  [Patient]
where [No_] = @NO
or DATEOFBIRTH = @DOB
end
ALTER TABLE tempName alter column Name varchar (30) NULL
INSERT INTO tempName (Name) values ('Nothing')
SELECT case Name
when '' then ''
when 'Nothing' then '*Nothing'
else Name
end Name
from tempName
order by [Name]
drop table tempName
```

Can someone help?

Comment: If you are running in visual studio, there should be more details as to why the dataset failed. Please check

Comment: Hi i left the the 1st code till the 6th out. My parameters are working now. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

table "tempname" is an actual table or it's a temporary table? In the latter case you need to call it with #temptable

Comment: hi it's a temporary table. it's working now i've removed the code starting from declare till set